# Javascript filter on html table does not work if it is injected to div. if table is loaded with page it works

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I want to filter out table before loading it to reduce it's size that it would load faster, when its loaded i would like to let user to filter it. I am using public CDN script for filter part, but it does not work on content which is injected to . It only works if whole table is loaded together with page.. what i'am doing wrong?

```
Jsfilter:  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tablefilter/2.5.0/tablefilter.js"></script>
```

DetailedRport.html

```
//this function called on button click it gets user and date to resize data set
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("month-input").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("email2").value;

 //here is called server side script
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).functionToRunOnFormSubmit(y, z);
}
//Resized data set gets injected to tbody
  function onSuccess(c){
  var table=toHTMLTable(c); 
  document.getElementById('myOutput1').innerHTML = table;
}
//Array to HTML table
function toHTMLTable(a) {
  var content = a.map(function(row, i) {
    var rowHTML = row.map(function (col) {
      return "<td>" + col + "</td>";
    }).join("");

    return "<tr>" + rowHTML + "</tr>";
  }).join("");
  return content;
}    
</script>
//user selects criteria for data table
<b> Report for:</b>
<select value="" name="email2" id="email2" width="300" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
   <?!= myEmails(); ?>
</select>

<b>Pick Period :</b>
<select name="Student" id="month-input" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
   <?!= myDates(); ?>
</select>
//On click table is loaded based on selection
<input type="button" value="Load Data" class="loadbutton" onclick="myFunction();" >

<br><br>
//Js tablefilter which should work but does not if table is injected
<table id="table1"class="mytable TF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
 <tr class="header">
  <th style="width:5%;">TASK</th>
  <th style="width:20%;">PROJECT</th>
  <th style="width:30%;">DATE</th>
  <th style="width:10%;">TIME SPENT</th>
  <th style="width:10%;">WORDCOUNT</th>
  <th style="width:10%;">SPEED</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
//Where data table is injected
<tbody id="myOutput1">

</tbody>
</table>
//Setting Js tablefilter source http://tablefilter.free.fr/
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var tf = setFilterGrid("table1");

</script>
```

server.gs

```
// here data set gets filtered based on users selection and is sent back
// Using ArrayLib library
function functionToRunOnFormSubmit(y,z)  {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var ActiveSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TogglMap");
  var StartRow = 2;
  var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;

  var EMWholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,2,RowRange,13);
  var AllValues = EMWholeRange.getDisplayValues();

  var dat = y +'-01'

  var removeCol = function(arr, colIndex, colIndex2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var row = arr[i];
      row.splice(colIndex, colIndex2);
    }
  }

  removeCol(AllValues, 5 , 6);
  var filteredArr1 =  ArrayLib.filterByText(AllValues, 1, z)

  var filteredArr2 =  ArrayLib.filterByText(filteredArr1, 3, dat)
  removeCol(filteredArr2, 1 ,1);

  Logger.log(AllValues)
  return filteredArr2
};
```

My goal is working JS filter

Comment: I managed to  find work around instead of using multifiler.js i used datatables.js from
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js

And added here Jquery:

function onSuccess(c){
var table=toHTMLTable(c); 
document.getElementById('myOutput1').innerHTML = table;

$('#table_id').DataTable(); 
}

Comment: you could add this solution as answer to your own question for the future googlers who may have the same issue.

Comment: I had the same issue. Resolved it by initialising the tableFilter at the end of the function  that inserts the data to the table. var tf = new TableFilter('tableID', config); tf.init();